# How to prevent from CronJob run process twice?

Tags: cron

I have a Cron Job scripts which runs every 4 minutes.
In rare cases the script is not finished within 4 minutes.
This causes problems.

How can I perform a check that if there the previous script is not finished then skip the current run

Expected behavior:

```
10:00 : Script A starts
10:04 : Script A2 starts - it finds that script A was not finish so this script aborts. Simply finish without doing nothing.
10:06 : Script A finish 
10:08 : Script A3 starts - no other scripts running so it continue
```

Notice: A, A2, A3 are the same script (just in different times)! It shouldn't consider other scripts that might be running also

Comment: You can do that within your script. With something like `ps -ax | grep MYSCRIPT`

Comment: @M.Becerra that won't work, the `grep` will always find itself. Try `pgrep -f MYSCRIPT` or `ps -ax | grep [M]YSCRIPT`.

Comment: What should happen if the script is still running? Should scriptB wait until scriptA is finished and then run? Should scriptB just exit and wait for the next time cron runs it? Please [edit] your question and explain what you need in more detail. Oh, and what language are the scripts written in?

Comment: It'll only make sense that the script, if still running, would exit it and wait until the next 4 minute mark, while logging the error somewhere maybe so you can look it up and see if it happens too often to adjust the time value inbetween the crons.

Comment: @terdon see my edit

Comment: Thanks, but we also need to know what these scripts are. Shell scripts? Perl scripts? Python scripts? it's trivial to implement logic that tests whether the script is running, but the details will depend on what language your script is written in (so I know to give you shell syntax for a shell script and not Perl, or whatever).

Comment: @terdon the script is .sh file regular bash

Comment: @terdon True that. And I see `pgrep` could be useful but I don't see what you mean with `ps -ax | grep [M]YSCRIPT`

Comment: @M.Becerra see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74185/22222

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two main approaches:

1. make the script exit if it detects another instance of itself running. Just add these lines to the beginning of your script:

   ```bsh
   if [ $(pgrep -c "${0##*/}") -gt 1 ]; then
        echo "Another instance of the script is running. Aborting."
        exit
   fi
   ```

   `$0` is the name of the script, and `${0##*/}` is the name of the script with everything until the last `/` removed (so, `/path/to/script.sh` becomes `script.sh`). This means that if you have another, unrelated script with the same name running, it will still be detected. on the other hand, it also means that it will work even if you call the script from a symlink. Which one you prefer depends on your use case.
2. Use a lock file and exit the script if the file exists:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   if [ -e "/tmp/i.am.running" ]; then
       echo "Another instance of the script is running. Aborting."
       exit
   fi
   else
       touch  "/tmp/i.am.running"
   fi

   ## The rest of the script goes here

   rm "/tmp/i.am.running"
   ```

Comment: regarding 1. It doesn't work for me. lets simplify it... My script name is "abcd". you can assume that there no where in the system another script with that name.. so all I need is to check if this name is running. I don't understand what needs to be replaced in the code.

Comment: @avi replaced? Why should something be replaced? It might be simpler if you just pinged me (`@terdon`) in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

Comment: I don't understand the syntax. "${0##*/}" This should be replaced by my script name isn't it? also i don't understand what is gt 1  Is it the returned value of pgrep? if so 0 means that it's already running and 1 means that no running http://howtounix.info/man/FreeBSD/man1/pgrep.1

Comment: @avi no, `-gt 1` just means "greater than one". The `pgrep -c foo` will print the number of processes named `foo` that are currently running. And don't use that man page, the FreeBSD tools are often very different from Linux ones.

Comment: I had to add -f option to pgrep for the first approach to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `run-one` command (`apt-get install run-one`)

From https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/run-one.1.html

> run-one  -  run  just  one  instance at a time of some command and unique set of arguments
> (useful for cronjobs, eg)

There are other useful wrappers like:

> run-this-one, run-one-constantly, keep-one-running, run-one-until-success, run-one-until-failure